# How to make date input field readonly in Cake PHP

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.3

Is there any standard way of making the date input field readonly in CakePHP.

I have the following code:

```
echo $this->Form->input('testDate',array(
                            'label' => 'date',
                            'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
                            'minYear' => date('Y') - 20,
                            'maxYear' => date('Y') - 0
                        )
                    )
```

I have tried the following way:

```
echo $this->Form->input('testDate',array(
                            'label' => 'date',
                            'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
                            'minYear' => date('Y') - 20,
                            'maxYear' => date('Y') - 0,
                            'disabled' => 'disabled'
                        )
                    )
```

That works fine (make the input field diable) but ofcourse I can't POST, So I tried 'readonly' => 'readonly' instead of disabled at the same way and this is not working. Do I have to use any other way (ex. Javascript)? Where am I making mistakes? Thanks for all the suggestions

Comment: Try this

'echo $this->Form->input('testDate',array(
                            'label' => 'date',
                            'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
                            'minYear' => date('Y') - 20,
                            'maxYear' => date('Y') - 0,
                            'readonly' =>true
                        )
                    );'

Comment: Hi Rohit, I already tried that as well :(

Comment: cake2 or cake3? Please check the tags

Comment: @modon I tried this and it works at my end are you adding some JS to this field.

Comment: No JS is been added and I am using cake3, is it a cake version issue?

Comment: I dont think so as I used the same code that I provided you in my cake3 setup and I am getting the desired result. If you could share a URL then I can debug this further.

Comment: Which version are you using 2X or 3X?

Comment: If 3X ,just add this  'readonly' => 'readonly'

Comment: I hate to be the one to give you bad news but unfortunately, this is not possible. If you disable a field, that field will not post, as you have discovered. Are you trying to build a date / time picker that forces the user to choose a date / time to be submitted?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo $this->Form->input('testDate',array(
                            'readyonly' => true
                        )
                    )
```